# problems including javascript at the end of html

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, asset-pipeline

The bootstrap template I'm using suggests putting all javascript files at the bottom of the html so pages load faster and I think this is a good idea. But some js libraries expect jquery to be included at the top. I'm tempted to put just jquery at the top but the rails asset pipeline really wants to mash up all my js together. What's the best way to deal with this?
For an example, I'm using ckeditor and when I do the suggested:

```
<%= form.cktext_area :notes, :toolbar => 'Full', :width => 800, :height => 400 %>
```

I get: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" in Chrome's console.

Answer (score 0):

According to the demo here https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor you can decide the location of the javascript tag for ckeditor using javascript_include_tag in your template code. The form helpers should only output HTML.

Slightly off-topic: If you find yourself using more and more javascript and want to have a common way of including scripts and depending scripts on each other, have a look at requirejs. There is even a version called requirejs-jquery that you can use if jquery is a requirement througout your site.

Comment: Hmm, I can decide the location of the javascript but if I decide to put it at the end of the html (which is what bootstrap suggests), the result is an error. Requirejs seems like more of an alternative to sprockets, I don't think I'm ready to give up on sprockets just yet.

Comment: Do you have an example page where the javascript is being loaded? It would be helpful to see in what order things are being executed.

Comment: I don't but execution order is the problem. The lib doesn't allow for delaying initialization until assets are loaded. I'm hoping someone can suggest a workaround but I think I'm going to be disappointed.

Comment: Can you at least paste just the HTML output of the page where you're seeing the issue? Basically just the "view source" from Firefox. I'm just curious as to how it's being loaded.